# How can I preconfigure customized default remotes in a shared git repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm setting up a shared git repository for my team using gitolite.  We have multiple projects, the same project is hosted on github as well as internally.

When a team member clones from the internal project repository, I want the remotes already specified with no client configuration necessary via git-config.  Something like this:

```
$ git clone git@internal.com:project
$ git remote -v
origin git@github.com:project/project-repository.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:project/project-repository.git (push)
internal git@internal.com:project/project-repository.git (fetch)
internal git@internal.com:project/project-repository.git (push)
```

Of course I have tried to use git remote add and then push internal --all but that doesn't seem to push my client's remotes.

What I want to avoid are team members having to configure their git client to do this:

```
git remote add internal git@internal.com:project/project-repository.git
```

What do I need to do to configure the internal repository to add these custom default remotes upon cloning the internal repository?

Comment: Commit a script that runs all the git commands you want. Then the other users can just run the script (at their discretion).